# Can i make limit cart quantity app using shopify or it need shopify plus and if i can mack then whats an alternative of refresh page every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am trying to create limit cart quantity application in shopify but i think it just need to shopify plus,is it real ? and if it didn't need shopify plus then i have one more question about my application.

I add multiple items in cart but it didn't display any error message about limit cart quantity is reached maximum,But i refresh page and click checkout button then it display that message.

Is there any alternative of refresh that page then please mention it in your answer.
Thank yo in advance....

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved

Comment: jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/cart.js',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data1) {
      console.log(data1);
    }
  })
count cart product using this ajax api and check all min max quantity in js file and add this script when app install. but script load, when refresh theme. i need when cart update that time load my script.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: how to check cart total every-time when quantity change in shopify using js.

Comment: Have any idea for this ?